# Is there a way to delete data under a certain chunk?

Tags: dolphindb

Take an example: there are 10 chunks in a partition 2015.09.10. Now I want to delete the fourth chunk in this partition, how to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delete clause as follows:

```
delete from table_name where Date_Time_Mark = 2015.09.01 and hashBucket(Contract_ID, 10) = 4
```